# Optimal way to conditionally perform calculations in function definition

Tags: c++, optimization

I have a simulation that does a set of calculations for a very large number of steps (on the order of 1e11). However not every calculation needs to be done for every simulation (though for any simulation the same calculations must be done every step). Since the simulations take so much time to run, even a single `if` statement each step has a significant impact on the overall computation time so I am trying to remove the need for `if` statements that will evaluate the same on every step. 
    For a small set of calculations this can be accomplished fairly easily by simply defining different functions and using whichever does the right combination of calculations, i.e.

```
void justA() {
  // calculate A
}
void justB() {
  // calculate B
}
void both() {
  // calculate A
  // calculate B
}
```

And use a function pointer to pre-determine which to use (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580547/conditional-function-definition) question). But for a larger set of possible calculations this becomes impractical. Obviously this could be solved with a series of `if` statements, i.e.

```
if (calculateA) {
  // calculate A
}
if (calculateB) {
  // calculate B
}
// ...
if (calculateZ) {
  // calculate Z
}
```

But for a 1e11 step simulation this requires a 1e11 evaluations for *each* calculation (all of which will evaluate to the same result).

**My question:** is there a way to do this without the per-call `if`s that doesn't require hard coding a different function for every possible combination of calculations?

---

**Note** - This has to be done at run-time, not using C++ preprocessor directives.

Comment: Put the loop inside the if statement?

Comment: I did think of that but that still has the issue of needing a hard-coded `if` for every possible combination - `if (a && b) {}`, `if (a)`, `if (b)`, etc. unless I am missing something (in which case that could work)

Comment: Could you use a vector of function pointers and add the relevant calculations to it at the start?

Comment: Perhaps you could create a program to write all the combinations of calculations.

Comment: @DBBaxter Yeah I had thought of that, not inclined to resort to that just yet haha

Comment: @Ian4264 That might actually work, I will try it. Thanks

Comment: @WilliamMiller Did the suggestion from Ian4264 work?

Comment: @Ghost Haven't tried it yet, if it does I will make it an answer

Answer (score -1):

I assume you don't have 1e11 = 100,000,000,000 (one hundred billion) *distinct* operations that might be performed. If you do then I guess you have a *lot* of memory to store the program. Instead I assume you have a much smaller number of operations that can be performed many times in some order.

How is that order determined? The solution will depend largely on this.

Note that the cost of an `if` is actually (essentially) zero, *if* the branch predictor successfully predicts the branch direction. In practice (and especially in scenarios like yours) it very often gets it right. The issue is the size of the branch predictor's lookup table. It isn't big enough to remember millions of branches. But, if you can reduce the branching to a small number - perhaps by having a single outer loop that iterates over the elements of an array of function pointers and calls each in turn - you can rely on the branch predictor getting it right every time (the branch will always lead to the beginning of the loop except for the very last time).

On real hardware, the expensive bit isn't the `if`, it's the branch, and most other control flow constructs like `do`/`while` and `for` also involve branching.

Comment: I don't understand, are you saying the branch predictor will look through a list of disparate `if` statements, decide which blocks to execute, execute only those blocks and have (essentially) zero overhead in evaluating the many `if` statements?

Comment: @WilliamMiller Yes. But it may not work if you have so many `if` statements that the branch predictor can't "remember" them all.

Comment: What is 'essentially' zero? Doesn't it still have to do the evaluations for each `if`?

Comment: The key is that the processor will begin speculative execution of code beyond the branch, using the direction it _thinks_ the branch will take before the branch condition is actually computed. If it guesses wrong, it then has to unwind any side effects of the incorrectly-executed code and start over. If it guesses right, there is zero overhead because the processor never stopped executing instructions. However, not _all_ instructions can be speculatively executed.

Comment: So a series of `if` statements, one for each calculation, will be as fast as having different functions for each combination (assuming the instructions therein can be speculatively executed and the predictor gets it right)?

Comment: I have tested this, using a series of `if` statements each containing one calculation is 25% slower for 2 calculations and 30% slower for 3 calculations than having a different function called for each combination of calculations. I think that this answer holds *only if* the loop is inside the `if` statement but that scheme does not satisfy my requirements.

Comment: This answer seems to have misunderstood the constraints of the question, the branch predictor is not a solution here since the `if`s are (and must be) inside the loop.